# Script consecutive Replace-All operations in Notepad++

Tags: scripting, replace, notepad++

Is there a way to script consecutive Replace-All operations in Notepad++?
For example, I want to be able to first replace all “ characters with `&ldquo` and then to replace all ” characters with `&rdquo` and then I would like to replace all "string1" with "string2", etc...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,

I finally figured it out, and it seems like a great solution.

I used PythonScript for NotePad++ (which is what I started with but which kept giving me errors, until I finally fixed a few things).

So, here is the code for those who may be interested:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os, sys
editor.replace(r"“",r"&ldquo;")
editor.replace(r"”",r"&rdquo;")
editor.replace(r"’",r"&rsquo;")
```

the `r` before the quotation marks allows the use of special characters as they are, and this is what was so difficult for me to get working.

Comment: But where's the 'all' part in 'replace all'?  This only replaces.